# jQuery templates each "value is not defined"

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I am having an issue with jQuery templates. I have a simple template each loop:

```
{{each gameVersions}}
    <option value="${$value}" {{if max_game_ver == value}}selected="selected"{{/if}}>${$value}</option>
{{/each}}
```

The browser is throwing the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: value is not defined`. According to the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-each/) value should be accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `value` by its placeholder `${$value}`. Try this.

```
{{each gameVersions}}
    <option value="${$value}" {{if max_game_ver == "${$value}"}}selected="selected"{{/if}}>${$value}</option>
{{/each}}
```